# how to code correct URI regex

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

having different URI pattern trying to find out correct regex to cover all of them, for example:

1) href="http://site.example.com/category/
and
2) href="http://site.example.com/en/page/

Using href=".+..+..+/(.+?)" respects first url, in second url skip en/page.

How to read everything after href="http://site.example.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[^\./]+\.[^\./]+\.[^\./]+(?:/(.*))?
```

That is:

`[^\./]+` = (anything but `.` and `/`)
`\.` = dot
`...?` = Zero or one occurrence(s) of `...`
`(?:...)?` = Zero or one of `...`, which is more than one character, but without capturing `...`.
`(?:/(.*))?` = Capture everything after the last `/`, if there is one.

Tested **[here](http://regexr.com/)**.

Comment: Thank you Siguza, it helped me to solve the issue.
Here what I use [^\./]+\.[^\./]+\.[^\./]+(?:/(.*?))

Answer (score 0):

`.` in regex means `any character (except \n newline)`, `+` means `one or more of the previous expression`, `?` means `0 or 1 of previous expression; also forces minimal matching when an expression might match several strings within a search string` (e.g. http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx). 

A literal dot is matched by `\.`.

So your regex boils down to `at least five signs, a slash sign, at least one sign, but you don't have to`. 

Meaning it matches even `http:/`. And it *does* match both of your examples (tested with `egrep` and `grep -P`), but only if you replace `href="` by `href=\"` and leave the last `"` out. Otherwise it will match none.

What you probably wanted was something like:

```
.+\..+\..+/.*
```

Or, if you want to be sure to match only urls, you might consider

```
http[s]?://([a-z]+\.)?[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/?[a-z/]?
```

The `http[s]?:` as a fixed part starts the expression (the s in case the ref comes from a secure connection). `[a-z]` means `match only lowercase letters`. As you might stumble upon sites that don't have a subdomain in the name like stackoverflow.com, the first `[a-z]+\.` is questionmarked. The end of url slash, too. `[a-z/]` means `match only lowercase letters and slashes`.

Comment: Thank you hnkchnsk, I tried similar pattern like .+\..+\..+\/(.*?) somehow it was not complete.